# nginx upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, apple-m1

Im working in a project with a docker stack containing nginx, tomcat and mariadb. My machine is a m1 macbook pro. My colleague on a linux machine (ubuntu 20.04) does not experience the problem. I get from time to time Error like "upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream" in the nginx log which I tried to resolve but it is still happening.

What I already tried:

- Setting a higher `proxy_read_timeout` in nginx conf
- added this to nginx conf:

  ```
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Connection "";
  ```

Comment: Make sure that the upstream server is reachable from Nginx machine. You can use telnet command to check connectivity.